# Next.js 14 - Middleware never runs, how do I correctly implement?

Tags: next.js, middleware

I'm working on a Next.js 14 app while learning Next.js and to some extent React at the same time. I'm probably just doing something wrong.

I'm using Xano to register and login users. My goal is to use middleware to check the routes against the Xano authToken cookie, (right now on all routes for simplicity and later I will change it to just routes that need protection).

I understand that I need to have the middleware.ts at the root of the project, (I'm not using a SRC folder). So, I've placed it at the same level as my package.json. It looks like this right now:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default function middleware(req: any) {
  console.log('run middleware');
}
```

I expected this to confirm it would run on every route, (using next/Link to navigate), and then add my auth logic. I do not see anything in the console. It's either not working, or I'm misunderstanding how this should work.

Can anyone shed some light on what I should expect and do here?

Comment: Try deleting the `.next` folder and starting your application. maybe that helps. I've just opened a new nextjs 14 project in codesandbox and added this simple middleware, and it is working! (https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/wild-cache-cwfl2l)

Comment: Worth a try but it had no effect. Interesting that the sandbox works. I'll have to compare files. My build started with that same template.

Comment: @Arashjahanbakhshan Your sandbox led me to realize I was looking at the wrong console so thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I should just delete my post or admit how much of a dope I am. Guess I'll leave this for the next dummy lol. I was looking at the browser console, not terminal. It's working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're exporting the function expecting it to "just work."  Keep in mind that all exporting a function does is make it available to be imported somewhere else.  Are you doing that somewhere?

Comment: None of the examples I see import it anywhere. My understanding is that the special file "middleware" should run for every request. I suppose defining "request" would help here. I'm not sure if navigating to a route constitutes a request.

Comment: It does, as navigating to a route is a request for the resource located there.